# What are my options to handle Raster Clipper ERROR 6: ADRG driver doesn't support 4 bands?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I have a tif file which contains 4 bands (RGB + alpha). The clipper does not work and gave me the message below;

```
ERROR 6: ADRG driver doesn't support 4 bands. Must be 3 (rgb) bands.
```

Any patch file or solution to this problem?  BTW I'm using QGIS 2.4 on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5

Alan B. Loreto
Faculty, Dept of Geodetic Engineering, VSU

Comment: What input/output format are you using? ADRG does not seem to be fully compatible, see http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#ADRG